# Android/Java: How To Stop Download After 5 Seconds?

Tags: java, android, networking

I am using an AsyncTask to download a file, with the purpose of measuring the download speed of the connection. I want to stop the download after 5 seconds, so that I can check the total number of bytes downloaded and calculate the speed. Here's the code I am using (this is placed inside the doInBackground() method):

```
try{                
    InputStream is = new URL("http://www.domain.com/linux.iso").openStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long limitTime = System.nanoTime();
    long difference = 0;    

    while (difference < 5000000000){ /*5 billion nanoseconds = 5 seconds*/
        is.read(buf);
        limitTime = System.nanoTime();
        difference = limitTime - startTime;
    }           

    is.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When connected to WiFi this is working fine. The measured speed is pretty accurate, and it takes exactly 5 seconds to complete the test. Once I move to 3G, though, the test takes from 10 up to 15 seconds to complete (I noticed that the slower the connection the longer it takes to complete).

How come? I am guessing that the OS is waiting for the replies of the read() requests it sent, but not sure.

Do you know a way that will cap the download at 5 seconds no matter what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` is definitely a blocking call.  But I think this is a result of having to wait for the cell radio in the phone to power up to full power.

One way to tell for sure would be to open a browser, surf to a page, then after the page is loaded, do your test.

There was a very interesting Google IO talk this year about how the cell radio sits in an idle/low-power state most of the time, and takes a few seconds to "warm up"

I'll see if I can find the link to the video.

Edit: here's the video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM

Battery talk starts about 17:12

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM&feature=player_detailpage#t=1032s

Ramp-up is ~2 seconds it looks like.

A slide from the presentation:

[image]

Comment: Do you remember how long/how much data it takes to warm the cell up?

Comment: Good question.  I didn't remember but found the info and edited the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make sure to wait 2 seconds into the download before I start my time take.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate time calculation and download in different threads. You are right, since both are in the same thread, `limitTime = System.nanoTime();` will only get executed when `is.read(buf);` is completed

Comment: How to separate them though? Put download inside yet another thread?

Comment: Yes, you can let the time calculation Thread (or AsyncTask) cancel the download AsyncTask when 5 seconds are expired. I think you should make the InputStream as a global variable to close it after cancelling the download Thread (to prevent memory leak).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if it works:

```
final InputStream is = new URL("http://www.domain.com/linux.iso").openStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
long limitTime = System.nanoTime();
long difference = 0;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Callable<Object> task = new Callable<Object>()
{
    public Object call()
    {
        try
        {
            return is.read(buf);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
};

long endTime = 5000000000L;

while(difference < endTime)
{   
    Future<Object> future = executor.submit(task);
    limitTime = System.nanoTime();
    difference = limitTime - startTime;

    try
    {
        if(future.get(endTime - difference, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) == null)
        {
            System.out.println("IOException is raised on read()!");
        }
    }
    catch(TimeoutException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("TimeoutException is raised, because of the timeout!");
        break;
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    finally
    {
        future.cancel(true);
    }
}
```