# How to run an AsyncTask every x minutes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an asynctask which retrieve data from webserviece. I want to run this task every 5 minutes to get the updated data from the server, but till now I don't know how can I do it.

I tried this code but my AsyncTask didn't stop

```
    //...
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
    new AddStringTask().execute();
    }
  }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: Timer won't go when your app is not the foreground process. If you want to run some script every five minutes wheter your app is launched or not (not recommended) then `AlarmManager` is your friend: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: You should NOT connect to the internet every 5 mins, you will kill the user's battery very, very quickly because you wont let the cell radio go into low-power mode. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378289/android-java-how-to-stop-download-after-5-seconds/12378378#12378378  Note: this may not apply as much if the user is on WiFi, but it still applies. Check out C2DM if you need push noptifications.

Comment: if I want it for each 15 minutes what is the solution for this .

Answer (score 3):

As being suggested from others, you should use Push ([GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)) instead of Poll. taken from [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) say:

> Poll might easy to implement, but you will never be actually
>   real-time. If you polling interval is 30 min, you can get a message
>   that is 29 minutes and 59 seconds late. Moreover, polling more often
>   than every 15-30 min will kill your battery pretty quickly:
>   https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/mobile-java-push/blog/save-device-battery-mobile-java-push

Answer (score 1):

As Michal K said, you can use `AlarmManager` with a `Service` and/or `BroadcastReceiver` to wake your app periodically.

However, **in order to preserve the user's battery I highly recommend not polling the connection.**

Instead, you can use **[Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)** or **GCM** *(formerly called C2DM)*

Here's the site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

**EDIT**

The main benefit here is that Android phones that have Google accounts will already poll Google's servers periodically.  They do this with cooperation from the carriers (like Verizon/AT&T).  Because of this, the radio can go into low power mode and receive push notifications.  By using Google's service, you enable a way for your app to receive data via push notifications without causing any extra battery drain.

====================

*(Also, here is some of the info from my other post about this).*

There was a very interesting Google IO talk this year about how the cell radio sits in an idle/low-power state most of the time, and takes a few seconds to "warm up".  They also discuss the perils of how polling the internet periodically will really drain the battery.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM

Battery talk starts about 17:12

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwC1OlJo5VM&feature=player_detailpage#t=1032s

A slide from the presentation:

[image]

Comment: Your `BroadcastReciver` should start your own `Service`, where you can call `AsyncTask`s and do work there.  `BroadcastReceiver`s are not meant to do any heavy lifting.